# How to support netsted resources in ActiveWeb

Tags: rest, routes, javalite, activeweb

Two models named "Post" and "Comment", and I want to build RESTful route like `/post/123/comment/8` and `CommentsController` handles all RESTful actions.

I have tried

```
route("/posts/{post_id}/comments/*").to(CommentsController.class);
```

and

```
route("/posts/{post_id}/comments/*").to(CommentsController.class).get().post().put().delete();
```

And none works:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not a RESTful set of routes from the point of AvctiveWeb framework: http://javalite.io/routing#restful-routing.

What you are trying to do is to define some custom routes. Not to say that they are not REST - based though.

Here is the example that works:

The route:

```
public class RouteConfig extends AbstractRouteConfig{
    public void init(AppContext appContext) {
        route("/posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}").to(CommentsController.class).action("index").get();
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class CommentsController extends AppController {
    public void index(){
        respond("index, post:" + param("post_id") + ", comment: " + param("comment_id"));
    }
}
```

then hit this:

http://localhost:8080/posts/123/comments/456

and observe:

`index, post:123, comment: 456`